# Почему теряется реактивность при деструкции vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

У меня есть стор pinia, со следующей структурой:

```
worksheets: [
foo: {worksheetData: {someProp: 'value1', anotherProp: 'value2'}}, 
bar: {worksheetData: {someProp: 'value21', anotherProp: 'value22'}},
]
```

Я хочу получить реактивный доступ к read/write someProp. При чем этот доступ требуется в многих местах, поэтому писать все время `worksheetStore().worksheets[index].worksheetData.someProp`  неудобно. Кроме того, кроме someProp еще много полей.
Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
const worksheetStore = useWorksheetStore();
const {someProp, anotherProp} = toRefs(worksheetStore[index].worksheetData)
```

Реактивность не работает. Например, если `someProp.value++` - то в сторе значения обновляются, но в шаблоне нет. Даже прямая привязка `const someProp = worksheetStore.worksheets[currentNameSpace].worksheetData.someProp` - тоже не работает. Значения читаются, но при записи реактивности нет, не срабатывает watcher, шаблон не обновляется.
Собственно вопрос, как вернуть эту реактивность?
UPD: Точнее реактивность срабатывает если в поле записать в том же в компоненте, в котором чтение. Если это значение меняется внутри условного экшона pinia, то реактивность не срабатывает.

Comment: Давайте репродукцию, потому что код, который вы дали даже просто синтаксически некорректен, он просто не запустится